# Replace a text that has keyframes in a template totally with another text

Tags: after-effects, keyframes

I have a textbox in a template with full of animations and keyframes,

How can I replace it totally with a new textbox that I recently created? (The recently created textbox have some language features that the basic textbox doesn't have/support)

In another hand. as an alternative solution, how can I **copy all the keyframes** and features of that textbox and add them to the recent textbox.

[image]

**Notes:**

1. Don't want to type in the same textbox (Will miss the new supported languages features)
2. Deleting the old one and replace it with the new one, will not add the animation to the 2nd text.

Comment: Have you tried simply selecting your keyframed effects and copy-pasting them onto your new text-layer?

Comment: Backed to this a bit late, not sure if I get you correctly, can you explain this with steps? 1. Copy the effects below the TextBox 2. move to the desired TextBox 3. Paste there? Such a thing? Will this work? doesn't have the project now, may need to test it a bit later, BTW if you liked you can add it as an answer, if it worked will mark it then.

Comment: Yes, this will work. If you copy an effect that has keyframes, the keyframes will be copied aswell.